# Java, update stage in a for loop

Tags: java, javafx

I have made a Java application that creates images. I would like to place the code, which is inside a for loop, to be in another for loop that updates the stage/screen every time the code finishes and returns to the first for loop, but it seems that using the setScene method and the show method don't seem to help if I put them inside the first for loop.

For the example below, I would like the circle drawing to happen on their own, instead of by clicking. I am thinking every 100ms using the thread.sleep method.

```
package javaFX;

import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Toolkit;

import javafx.application.Application;

import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.canvas.Canvas;
import javafx.scene.canvas.GraphicsContext;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class circles extends Application {

    Dimension screenSize = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
    double WIDTH = screenSize.getWidth() - 80;
    double HEIGHT = screenSize.getHeight() - 80;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        Group root = new Group();
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, WIDTH, HEIGHT, Color.WHITE);
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
        root.getChildren().add(canvas);
        GraphicsContext graphics = canvas.getGraphicsContext2D();
        primaryStage.setTitle("Circles!");

        canvas.setOnMouseClicked(clickEvent -> {
            for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
                double ran = Math.random() * WIDTH;
                double nu = Math.random()*1000;
                int ranNum = (int) nu;
                graphics.strokeOval(ran, ran, ran, ran);
            }
        });     
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.setResizable(false);
        primaryStage.show();
    }
}
```

Comment: Please add your code to the question so that people can understand this issue and can help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem Solved! Use an `AnimationTimer`, like so:

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Toolkit;

import javafx.animation.AnimationTimer;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.canvas.Canvas;
import javafx.scene.canvas.GraphicsContext;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Testing extends Application {

    Dimension screenSize = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
    double WIDTH = screenSize.getWidth() - 80;
    double HEIGHT = screenSize.getHeight() - 80;

    @Override public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        Group root = new Group();
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, WIDTH, HEIGHT, Color.WHITE);
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
        root.getChildren().add(canvas);
        GraphicsContext graphics = canvas.getGraphicsContext2D();
        primaryStage.setTitle("Circles!");

        // canvas.setOnMouseClicked(clickEvent -> {
        // for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
        // double ran = Math.random() * WIDTH;
        // graphics.strokeOval(ran, ran, ran, ran);
        // }
        // });

        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.setResizable(false);
        primaryStage.show();

        new AnimationTimer() {
            @Override public void handle(long currentNanoTime) {
                for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
                    double ran = Math.random() * WIDTH;
                    graphics.strokeOval(ran, ran, ran, ran);
                }

                try {
                    Thread.sleep(100);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // Do nothing
                }
            }
        }.start();
    }
}
```

JavaFX will not update it for you. The problem with using something like a while loop is that JavaFX doesn't know that you're done with the instructions (or at least, that's the impression I've gotten from the Docs) and commence the draw process. There also does not seem to exist something to manually force a redraw. So, you have to use an AnimationTimer.

Comment: You really shouldn't call `Thread.sleep` within an `AnimationTimer` (as this will temporarily freeze the JavaFX application thread and your entire application, including input processing and other animations).  Instead, if you want to do things periodically, look to [Timeline](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/animation/Timeline.html).

Comment: @jewelsea, agreed. But there are no inputs to worry about. Freezing the application thread has no effect on the user because the thread isn't looking for anything.